# Adding class to Wordpress function

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm having difficulty adding a class to a wordpress element. I want to add the object-fit: cover element to a Wordpress function, but I'm running into a wall.

```
<!--    Row     -->
<article class="col-4">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?></a>
</article>
```

I'm attempting to directly add the object-fit:cover to the img through CSS, but it doesn't effect it. Totally confused because its being effected by the width: 100% and height: auto.

```
.col-4 img{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

I've tried taking the width and auto off and just having the object-fit: cover, but it still doesn't take effect on the page.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please consider using background image rather than object-fit cover. It does not support in all browsers. Even IE11 and edge does not support it. http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.col-4 img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px; // height should be mentioned so that image can cover that place
  object-fit: cover; // Image will fill the 200px space
}
```

For `object-fit: cover`,  the height should be mentioned so that the image can cover that height.

I would recommend you to use background image rather than `object-fit cover`. Please check http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit for compatibility with other browsers.

Source on how to use background size cover

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-image` or simply make the image `width: 100%`

**1. Using background-image**

You have to set the height of the image or  [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

```css
.article-photo {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article class="col-4">
 <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="article-photo" style="background-image: url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>')">
    </a>
 <?php endif; ?>
</article>
```

**2. Image with width: 100%**

```css
.article-photo {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.article-photo img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article class="col-4">
 <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="article-photo">
     <?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?>
    </a>
 <?php endif; ?>
</article>
```